# Can I use 1 Shared Storage for Multiple Windows 2003 Clusters?

Tags: windows, sql, vmware-esx, cluster

My Environment:
Dell PowerVault 220S connected via SCSI to 2 Dell Poweredge 2950s.
I have installed ESX 4i on each of the 2950s, and do NOT have VCenter.  I will be using Windows Server 2003 Datacenter on each server for 3 installs, a SQLDEV, SQLTEST, and SQLPROD.  They will each be clustered, so machine 1 will have a SQLTEST, and machine 2 will have SQLTEST-2.  The same for the others.

My question:  How many Disk Partitions will I need on the PowerVault to handle clustering?  They will be 2-node clusters for each OS.  I'd like to get away with 1 Partition for each of the Cluster components.  But as I read, that may not be possible.  I know I need 1 partition for MSDTC, 1 for Quorum, and 1 for DATA.  I'm thinking I will need 3 Quorums, 3 MSDTC, and 1 Data.  Is this correct?  Or will I need 3 DATA also?

Many thanks for any input you can provide.

Matthew Williams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a single VMFS partition/datastore to store the actual VMs, they you'll need a single RDM LUN for each of the MSDTC, Quorums and shared data mounts for each cluster (i.e. three data). The reason is that this isn't a 6-way cluster but 3 x 2-way clusters right?

Comment: Correct.  I have the VM's stored locally on each server, with the shared data in the middle.  Thanks for the quick answer.  I was hoping to avoid 3 data partitions, but I'll make do.

Comment: I'd be tempted to store the VMs centrally too if I were you, that would prepare you better for moving to using VC if you ever need HA/DRS/SVM etc.

Comment: Great answer. Storing the VMs on shared storage is an excellent recommendation even without VC it allows you to swap out the actual server hardware pretty easily - moving the VM's then just becomes a case of de-registering the VM in one host and re-registering it on another.